# discord.js-commando arguments on a command with different responses

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, commando

I'm trying to get my bot to run different responses after a command like >open well open what? >open door and the bot would respond with opening door or something along those lines I've read the discord command documentation I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how it works I know how to do arguments without commando but id love to know how to do it with commando the best I can think of is }else{ but I don't know how to check for args then to verify any ideas? ive tried the arguments in the documentation can't seem to get a response.

```
run(message) {
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    return message.say('*Your wand projects a stream of water*');

}else{
    if (command === 'aguamenti cup') {
    return message.say('*Your wand projects a stream of water into a cup*');

}else{




}
}
```

tried this way doesnt seem to want to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript syntax is wrong or you aren't showing the whole code, `}else{` where is the if statement?

There's no reason to check what the command name is since it's already handled by discordjs-commando

```js
run(message) {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");
    args.shift();

    const subject = args[0];

    if (!subject) {
        return message.say("Open what?")
    } else if (subject === "door") {
        return message.say("Opening door");
    }
}
```

Comment: also see what i stuffed up there *facepalm*\